# How to categories items according to some specification in angular using ngFor

Tags: ngfor, angular10

I am trying to list doctors with some specialization. But the code below is creating several title with item of same specialization.

Below is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9" *ngFor="let doctor of doctors; let i = index">
            <h3 class="header-subtitle">{{doctor.doctorSpeciality}}</h3>
            <div class="doctor">
                <div class="doctor-description">
                    <h4 class="name-title">Dr. {{ doctor.doctorName}}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
</div>
```

The output I am getting is like:

### General Physician

doctor name1

### Cardiologist

doctor name2

### General Physician

doctor name3

Here, the doctor name3 of category general physician should be under heading of first header title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that you can achieve only in html (without some directives/pipes at least).

I don't know exactly how you .ts code looks like, but the grouping you're seeking for needs to be made on the actual collection that you're using inside *ngFor. Most likely `doctors` is a flat array of objects, something like below, on which you can use `reduce` and `map` for computing the groups.

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly doctors = [
    {
      doctorSpeciality: 'General Physician',
      doctorName: 'doctor name 1'
    },
    {
      doctorSpeciality: 'Cardiologist',
      doctorName: 'doctor name 2'
    },
    {
      doctorSpeciality: 'General Physician',
      doctorName: 'doctor name 3'
    }
  ];

  specialityGroupedDoctors = {};

  constructor() {
    this.computeGroups();
  }

  private computeGroups(): any {
    this.specialityGroupedDoctors = this.doctors.reduce(
      (acc: any, doc: any) => {
        if (!acc[doc.doctorSpeciality]) {
          acc[doc.doctorSpeciality] = [];
        }
        acc[doc.doctorSpeciality].push(doc);
        return acc;
      }, {});
  }
}
```

And then the html template needs to change to this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9" *ngFor="let group of specialityGroupedDoctors | keyvalue">
    <h3 class="header-subtitle">{{group.key}}</h3>
    <div class="doctor" *ngFor="let doctor of group.value">
      <div class="doctor-description">
        <h4 class="name-title">Dr. {{ doctor.doctorName}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here you have a StackBlitz sandbox where you can see it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t86wnc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This is how my ts file looks

response: Observable<any>;  doc =[];
  doctors = [];
  constructor(
    public getDoctor:DoctorRegistrationService,

  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDoctors();
  }
  public  getDoctors(){
    this.getDoctor.getDoctors().subscribe(response=>{
      this.doc=response;
      for(let i of this.doc){
        this.doctors.push(i.doctorModel);
      }
    });
  }

Comment: Ok, so `this.doctors` is a flat array taken from the server through a call in `DoctorRegistrationService`, on which you can safely apply the solution above. Take a look at the code from StackBlitz that I've created and apply that in your project. Btw, `this.computeGroups()` needs to be called after the `for(let i of this.doc)` block inside the subscribe callback.